# How to design a REST API endpoint with relations

Tags: rest, api-design, endpoint

I'm working on designing a RESTful API, and I'm facing a challenge when it comes to modelling and implementing endpoints for entities with many-to-many relationships.

**Example:**

The `Role` table stores roles that users can have, such as "admin," "user," "moderator," etc.

The `Permission` table stores individual permissions, such as "create_post," "edit_post," "delete_post," "comment," etc.

The `User_Role` table establishes a many-to-many relationship between users and roles, allowing a user to have multiple roles if needed.

The `Role_Permission` table establishes a many-to-many relationship between roles and permissions, allowing roles to have specific permissions associated with them.

For `Role` and `Permission` I have following schema:

```
POST /roles
GET /roles
GET /roles/[id]
PUT /roles/[id]
DELETE /roles/[id]

POST /permissions
GET /permissions
GET /permissions/[id]
PUT /permissions/[id]
DELETE /permissions/[id]
```

How should the endpoint url looks like for both relations? My idea is:

```
Create a New Role-Permission Relationship:
POST /role_permissions

Delete an Existing Role-Permission Relationship:
DELETE /role_permissions/[id]
```

Maybe `/roles/[id]/permissions/[id]` would work too?

I want to ensure that my API design is clean, efficient, and follows best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Role_Permission` does not have its own id, it is identified by the id of the role and the id of the permission. `/role_permissions/[id]` won't work as an endpoint therefore.

You can (and should) use

```
GET /roles/[id]/permissions
PUT|PATCH /roles/[id]/permissions
POST /roles/[id]/permissions/
GET /roles/[id]/permissions/[id]
DELETE /roles/[id]/permissions/[id]
```

or

```
GET /permissions/[id]/roles
PUT|PATCH /permissions/[id]/roles
POST /permissions/[id]/roles
GET /permissions/[id]/roles/[id]
DELETE/permissions/[id]/roles/[id]
```

or even both. Which to prefer depends on your domain: are the relations directed? Is the cardinality of one side much larger than the other? For a typical [part-of relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of) (where an entity is only part of one other entity), the composite goes first and the member goes second. For a [has-a relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) you'd usually use the same order - in your example, that's `/roles/[id]/permissions` not `/permissions/[id]/roles`, and `/users/[id]/roles` not `/roles/[id]/users`.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions. So in this case you set the permissionId as body in the request of POST /roles/[id]/permissions/ to create a new relationship?

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to add a permission to a role. Or do a `PATCH` on the same route where the body says "add permission(id)", or do a `PUT` on the same route with the entire list of permissions of that role.